# Eliminar estilo css desde vuejs?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Al cargar la pagina se me ve el div con una altura muy larga por unos segundos, por lo que decidi darle una altura estatica y al cargar los elementos esta altura (height) eliminarse en el css, pero no logro hacerlo o no se como definir desde vuejs el valor de la variable para que esta se aplique en el css, aqui el codigo:

```
 <section id = "start_packing" v-bind:style="{height:anchura}">
            <div class = "blocks">
                <div id="select_room">
                    <button type="button" @click="anchura"> anchura</button>
                    <label>Select room:</label>
                    <select v-model="room" @change="selectRoom"><option value="22">22</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="139">139</option><option value="158">158</option></select>
                    <a href="index.php"><button>Back</button></a>
                </div>
                <div id="no_products" v-if = "hide == true">
                    <p>There's no previous product made in this room.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

js:

```
computed: {
    computed: function() {
        return this.width;
    },
    computed_show_current_products: function() {
        return this.visibility;
    }
},
methods: {
  
    selectRoom: function() {
        axios.post("index.php?url=get_busyroom", {'room':this.room}).then((response)=>{ //GOES TO GET_BUSYROOM LINE 32 IN WEB.PHP
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                this.anchura = "null";
                this.visibility = "visible";
                this.message = "Room busy! Finish it first."
                this.hide = false;
                this.currentproduct = response.data;
                this.showcurrentProduct = true;
                this.showpreviousProduct = false;
                this.packagenewProduct = false;
            }else {
                this.showlastProduct(this.room);
            }
```

css:

```
#start_packing {
    width: 400px;
    background:rgba(0, 149, 144, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: puedes usar `!important` para tus elementos de la clase css para que tengan la preferencia, por ejemplo `height: 70px!important;`

Comment: como? alguna otra manera para evitar ese problemita? de que al cargar se ven los elementos por unos microsegundos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que ya pasaron varios meses de la pregunta, pero podrías jugar un poco con el ciclo de carga de vue y variables de visualización. Puedes crear un variable "loaded" que por default esté en false

```
data(){
  return {
    loaded: false
```

En tu función donde mandas llamar axios, cambiarla a true cuando ya tengas los datos

```
axios.post("index.php?url=get_busyroom", {'room':this.room}).then((response)=>{ //GOES TO GET_BUSYROOM LINE 32 IN WEB.PHP
            if (response.data.length > 0) {
                this.anchura = "null";
                this.visibility = "visible";
                this.message = "Room busy! Finish it first."
                this.hide = false;
                this.currentproduct = response.data;
                this.showcurrentProduct = true;
                this.showpreviousProduct = false;
                this.packagenewProduct = false;
                this.loaded = true
            }else {
                this.showlastProduct(this.room);
            }
```

Y en la vista solo mostrar el div si loaded es true

```
<div v-if="loaded" class = "blocks" >
```